# Socket.io 0.9 and 1.0 broadcast to all room members

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Which of the following syntaxes are correct to broadcast a message to all connected sockets within one room, in Socket.io 1.0 and Socket.io 0.9?

None of the below are sending messages to my client web console, which has a simple log statement, but at least four of them are sending to other clients.

How would I correctly emit a "joined_channel" message back to my connected client, and all other clients in the room?

```
Client

 socket.on('joined_channel', function(data){
    console.log('joined channel', data);    
})


 Server

 // this is for 0.9
      io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('joined_channel', data.room);

 // which version is this for? Any?
      socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('joined_channel', data.room);

 // is this to all connected users?
      io.sockets.emit('joined_channel', data.room);

 // To all connected users globally?
      io.emit('joined_channel', data.room);

 // how is socket different than io?
      socket.emit('joined_channel', data.room);

 // this is for 0.9 but does it work at all?
      io.sockets.to(data.room).emit('joined_channel', data.room);

 // this is as above but 1.0?
      io.to(data.room).emit('joined_channel', data.room);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is for the latest socket.io.

this is taken from http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/

```
//emit from server to everyone but the clients socket
socket.broadcast.emit('joined_channel', data);

//broadcast information to a certain room only (excluding the client)
socket.broadcast.to( data.room ).emit('joined_channel');

//broadcast information globally to a certain room
io.sockets.in( data.room ).emit('joined_channel');
```